# Clicking on a button that has onClick already on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this sounds silly, but I need to create a function that finds a button that has onClick attached to it. And then clicks it.

So like:

```
<div onclick="coolFunction()" class="coolClass">
   <p>Click Me!</p>
</div>
```

I tried searching for it by doing something like this:

```
$('.coolClass').attr('onClick') == 'coolFunction()'
```

Which did actually find it, the problem is I don't understand how can I click on it because it's in an if method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector would be something more like `$('[onclick="coolFunction()"]')`.

So to do what you describe, you could do this

```
 $('[onclick="coolFunction()"]').trigger('click');
```

Although, unless `coolFunction()` cares about being explicitly by this DOM element, you could just call `coolFunction()`, without having it piggy-back on your click handler.

**Update: With an argument**

```
 // Note selector is less specific, but still targeted
 $('[onclick^="coolFunction"]').trigger('click');
```

With, this, you can trigger the click handler, and `coolFunction(var)` in your HTML would work as expected.

Comment: Legend! you think I can use a variable inside the mentioned function? for example coolFunction(var)?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('.coolClass').attr('onClick') == 'coolFunction()' )
{
    $('.coolClass').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.coolClass').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.attr('onClick') == 'coolFunction()') {
        $this.trigger('click')
    }

});
```

This will select all elements with .coolClass, check if the onClick attribute matches the coolFunction call and trigger the click event on that element.

Answer (score 0):

As *couzzi* said, you can first verify if all the elements of the class **coolClass** have the attribut **coolFunction** and when it's the case you can just apply what you want to do on them.

```
$('.coolClass').each(function() {
$this = $(this);
if ($this.attr('onClick') == 'coolFunction()') {
    $this.trigger('click')
}
```